# Woocommerce | If page_id= .. { }

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, woocommerce

I am trying to apply specific functions to a certain page ID in Woocommerce.
However, it does not seem to apply. I have looked at both Wordpress and Woommerce conditional tags (https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/).

The simple code I am testing is shown below, but even that is not working.

```
if ( is_product()) {
    echo ' HALLO sdfdsfsdfsdfsdf ';
}
```

I have also tried with page_id and post_id but cannot get this to work.
I have added this code to my functions.php in my child theme.

Does anybody know to to write a specific function only for a specific product page (I know the value).

Comment: "specific product page"? Do you want to `echo` if it's a specific page or specific post? Plus, are you sure it is not echoing? Inspect Element -> Ctrl + F (Find) -> type " HALLO ...."

Comment: what action/filter you used?

Comment: @dzinee Did you check my code, by any chance?

Comment: Sorry I was a but sick the last few days. Thank you for all your suggestions! @purvik7373 I am trying your code now. I do not fully understand what you are saying, but would just copy pasting that code work?

Comment: @AntonisTsimourtos In the end I want a specific code only to work on a specific product (f.e. hide the review tab). But to test this I am just trying to echo something.

Comment: @AntonisTsimourtos Yes I looked into console and in the source code. It does not echo anything.

Answer (score 0):

### Method - 1

`is_page()` relies on a complete global **$wp_query** object. If you call it before the action `template_redirect` has been fired, it might be impossible to get that data.

```
add_filter( 'template_include', function( $template ) {
    if ( is_product() )
        echo 'HELLO';

    return $template;
});
```

---

### Method - 2

The WordPress/[WooCommerce](http://www.woothemes.com/woocommerce/) [conditional tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) won’t work until after the wp action is fired, making it the earliest point at which you can use the tags. You can view the entire list, and the order of the core WordPress actions at the Action Reference page.

```
add_action( 'wp', 'init' );
function init() {    
  if ( is_shop() ) {    
    echo 'HELLO, this works!';
  }    
}
```

Comment: Yes! I think Method 1 works. 
I get an Echo (which breaks the whole page) but gonna look now whether I can make certain things apply only to this product.

Can I ask you, how would you integrate the product ID?

Can you say

add_filter( 'template_include', function( $template ) {
    if ( is_product(190) )
        echo 'HELLO';

    return $template;
});

Or would you need to say something like id=190

Comment: edit: or would you need to use is_single?

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_single/

For now I tried:
add_filter( 'template_include', function( $template ) {
    if ( is_product(810) )
        echo 'HELLO';

    return $template;
});

Comment: I realise the question might have been not specific enough.
This is an example of the code I want to apply only to certain product:

Comment: @dzinee you can use something like this `global $product;
if( $product->id == 1 && is_product() ){
    echo 'HELLO';
}`.